# Custom blazor server-side authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-code, .net-5, blazor-server-side

I am new to blazor and stumbled across a problem when trying to implement authentication in my app. For now, I need to store all my users' data in JSON file and do not have a SQL DB to refer to, which, as I understand is needed to implement authentication.

As for now I have a list of users and check if the user is in my list of signed in accounts, then call markAsAuthenticated

```
public void markUserAsAuthenticated(string emailAddress)
    {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, emailAddress),
            }, "someType"); 

            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged (Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user)));
    }
```

I would like to add roles or claims now to be able to include them in the  component, but find it difficult to understand, what the following steps should be.
Most of the tutorials use Authorization services provided by VisualStudio, but we work in VSCode and I would like to implement this myself, so I can use the list of users I have.

I would also like to find out if I can use cookies or JWT in my app and if there are any good tutorials for that or suggestions considering work with VSCode and server-side work, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to store the users in a JSON file? If you absolutely must store users in a local file I would recommend using SQLite instead. You do not need to use sql for authentication in identity framework, however, you might have to write your own provider if you want to use a JSON file as storage.

Comment: *There's no difference between VS, VS Code or Emacs*. These are just the editors. Authentication and authorization are performed by your code, not the editor. Blazor Server is still an ASP.NET Core Web App and uses the same ASP.NET Core Identity infrastructure. What you ask is essentially how to use a different storage provider for ASP.NET Core Identity

Comment: BTW roles *are* part of authorization, that's why all tutorials mention it. Authentication is the mechanism that identifies a user. Authorization is the mechanism that specifies what that user can do. Part of it can be done by assigning roles to users

Comment: Thanks for the replies, perhaps using a legit DB is the option, we are about to learn them, that's why using JSON is the most understandable way for me as for now. When it comes to authorization and authentication I know the difference, the main issue is I do not know whether i should use role, policy (as I understand, claims are a specific case of policies) -based authentication to get this work done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use cookies you need to use a razor page (.cshtml). You can have a razor page inside a Blazor application. It's the same code you'd use in a traditional razor application (pre-Blazor).

There's nothing Visual Studio specific to this that I know of.

See https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/36

Comment: That's not what this link says. Blazor, both Server and WASM are SPAs running inside a browser tab and use cookies just like any other SPA